# Use Variable for filename and have date

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am looking to convert a pandas dataframe into a csv and use a variable for the filename.

Here's the code:

```
companydf.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\exports\test1.csv', index=False)
```

Instead of "test1" for the filename, I'd like to use a variable and have it followed by today's date.

Desired output:

```
file_name = example

companydf.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\exports\example m/d/y.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Your question simplifies to python string concatenation and a little bit of date formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you what you need

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

#using f-string and datetime you can dynamically set the filename to 'something' and put a date at the end
file_name = f"something_{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')}"

#This will use a combination of f-string and r-string to make a raw string referencing the filename from above
companydf.to_csv(fr'C:\Users\Admin\exports\{file_name}.csv', index=False)
```